# Spring Integration DSL Custom Error Channel Not Work

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I use DSL implementation of Spring Integration.
I have code below and I can not use my custom error flow. When authenticate method throws Runtime Exception, the errorChannel starts to process. I enrich header to use my custom error flow, but not use.

```
// In Class - 1
 @Bean
    public MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway marshallingWebServiceInboundGateway(BeanFactoryChannelResolver channelResolver, Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {

        MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway wsInboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway();
        wsInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("incomingRequest.input"));
        wsInboundGateway.setReplyChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("outgoingResponse.input"));
        wsInboundGateway.setErrorChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("errorChannel"));
        wsInboundGateway.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        wsInboundGateway.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return wsInboundGateway;
    }


// In Class - 2
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow incomingRequest() {
        return f -> f.<Object, Class<?>>route(t -> t.getClass(),
                mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping(payloadType1(),
                        sf -> sf.gateway("type1.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional))
                        .subFlowMapping(payloadType2(),
                                sf -> sf.gateway("type2.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)),
                        conf -> conf.id("router:Incoming request router"));
    }

// In Class - 3
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow type1() {
        IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = f -> f
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "error222", true))
                .<Type1>handle((p, h) -> authentication.authenticate(p),
                        conf -> conf.id("service-activator:Authenticate"))
                .transform(transformer::transformType1MsgToDataX,
                        conf -> conf.id("transform:Unmarshall type1 Message"))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(TypeDataIntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.MESSAGE_ID, "payload.id")
                        .headerExpression(TypeDataIntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.MESSAGE_TYPE, "payload.messageType"))
                .handle((GenericHandler<DataX>) repository::successResponseMessage,
                        conf -> conf.id("service-activator:return success"))
                .channel("outgoingResponse.input")
                ;

        return integrationFlow;
    }

// In Class - 3
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow error222Flow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("error222").handle("repository", "failureResponseMessage").get()

                ;

    }
```

**EDIT:**

After Artem's answers, my code like below. But still, I can't access header parameter in the error flow. I get error - "No channel resolved by router 'router:error response prepare' "

```
 // In Class - 1
 @Bean
    public MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway marshallingWebServiceInboundGateway(BeanFactoryChannelResolver channelResolver, Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {

        MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway wsInboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway();
        wsInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("incomingRequest.input"));
        wsInboundGateway.setReplyChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("outgoingResponse.input"));
        wsInboundGateway.setErrorChannel(channelResolver.resolveDestination("errorResponse.input"));
        wsInboundGateway.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        wsInboundGateway.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return wsInboundGateway;
    }


// In Class - 2
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow incomingRequest() {
        return f -> f.<Object, Class<?>>route(t -> t.getClass(),
                mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping(payloadType1(),
                        sf -> sf.gateway("type1.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional))
                        .subFlowMapping(payloadType2(),
                                sf -> sf.gateway("type2.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)),
                        conf -> conf.id("router:Incoming request router"));
    }

// In Class - 2
@Bean 
public IntegrationFlow errorResponse(){ 
    return f -> f.<MessageHandlingException, Object>route(t -> t.getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("ABCDEF"), 
                        mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping("ABCDEF", 
                                sf -> sf.gateway("customError.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)), 
                                conf -> conf.id("router:error response prepare"));
}

// In Class - 3
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow type1() {
        IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = f -> f
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", true)) 
                .<Type1>handle((p, h) -> authentication.authenticate(p),
                        conf -> conf.id("service-activator:Authenticate"))
                .transform(transformer::transformType1MsgToDataX,
                        conf -> conf.id("transform:Unmarshall type1 Message"))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(TypeDataIntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.MESSAGE_ID, "payload.id")
                        .headerExpression(TypeDataIntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.MESSAGE_TYPE, "payload.messageType"))
                .handle((GenericHandler<DataX>) repository::successResponseMessage,
                        conf -> conf.id("service-activator:return success"))
                .channel("outgoingResponse.input")
                ;

        return integrationFlow;
    }

// In Class - 3
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow customError(){
        return f -> f.handle((GenericHandler<MessageHandlingException>)eventRepository::failureResponseMessage,
                                conf -> conf.id("service-activator:return failure"));
    }
```

**EDIT - 2:**

I try Artem's test code, it works in this scenario. If I convert the type1 flow to the subflow mapping as below (I do it, because I'm doubtful my subflow code block), the error flow can't print ABCDEF parameter value.
After that, I add another header(XYZTWR) to the subflow mapping, but it can't be printed too.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow type1() {
    return f -> f.<String, String>route(t -> t.toString(), mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping("foo",
            sf -> sf.gateway("fooFlow.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional).enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("XYZTRW", "XYZTRW", true))));
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fooFlow() {
    return f -> f.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", true))
            .handle((p, h) -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
            });
}
```

My S.OUT is :

```
GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={history=testGateway,type1.input, id=1fad7a65-4abe-c41d-0b22-36839a103269, timestamp=1503029553071}]
```

Comment: I use spring integration 4.3.11 and spring integration java dsl 1.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `errorChannel` header starts work when we shift message to the different thread executor or queue channel. Otherwise standard `throw` and `try...catch` works in the same call stack.

So in your case the authentication exception is just thrown to the caller - WS Inbound Gateway. And here you have configured global error channel.

I did this testing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public static class ContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorResponse() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel())
                    .<MessagingException, Message<?>>transform(MessagingException::getFailedMessage,
                            e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100)))
                    .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow type1() {
            return f -> f
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", true))
                    .handle((p, h) -> { throw new RuntimeException("intentional"); });
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel errorChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
}

@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "errorChannel", defaultRequestChannel = "type1.input")
public interface TestGateway {

    Message<?> sendTest(String payload);

}

...

@Autowired
private TestGateway testGateway;

@Test
public void testErrorChannel() {
    Message<?> message = this.testGateway.sendTest("foo");
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

And my SOUT shows me:

```
GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={ABCDEF=ABCDEF, id=ae5d2d44-46b7-912d-17d4-bf2ee656140a, timestamp=1502999446725}]
```

Please, make DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and observe in which step your message is losing desired headers.

**UPDATE**

OK. I see your problem. Since you use `sf -> sf.gateway("fooFlow.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)`, in other words you call the downstream via gateway, everything you've done there is behind the door and you can get as guilty to back in case of error only what you send there - gateway's request message. The downstream `failedMessage` is swallowed by default.

To fix the problem you should consider an addition `errorChannel()` option for that `.gateway()` and handle the downstream error there. Or... just don't use `.gateway()` in the router's subflow, but simple `channel` mapping.

The `.transactional()` can be configured also on the any `.handle()`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but my another question is that I can't pass a parameter(like header map value) to the global error channel to decide my custom configuration in it.

Comment: You can just use custom error channel on the `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway` level instead.

Comment: If I could pass header parameter to the global error channel, it helps me, but I cannot. Is there a way for this? I need the starting flow name information for deciding the process of global error channel.

Comment: You really can use `.enrichHeaders()` on the matter. When exception happens downstream, it is wrapped to the `MessagingException` with the `failedMessage` property. Exactly this message has a desired header. The `ErrorMessage` sent to the errorChannel has that `MessagingException` as a payload. So, what you need is to cast the payload to the `MessagingException` and call its `getFailedMessage()` to get access to the "guilty" request message to drill down to its headers for desired option.

Comment: After your 1st answer, I replaced my first enrichment in type1 flow as below: .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", true)) and my error channel flow is that: @Bean
 public IntegrationFlow errorResponse(){
  return f -> f.<MessageHandlingException, Object>route(t -> t.getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("ABCDEF"),
    mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping("ABCDEF",
      sf -> sf.gateway("customError.input", ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)),
      conf -> conf.id("router:error response prepare")); but I get error:No channel resolved by router 'router:error response prepare'

Comment: So,  I cannot access my header parameter

Comment: You should show that new code in your question. That's to hard to read it from the comments. There is just simple EDIT functionality on the question.

Comment: Please, take a look into my answer from words: `I did this testing:`

Comment: Artem, I tried it and I editted my question as EDIT - 2. Thanks.

Comment: See an UPDATE, please.

Comment: I have one another question about error handling too. It is about handling the checked exceptions. If you want, I can ask it in different question. 
My authentication method also can throw checked exceptions and if I don't want to catch them, my IntegrationBuilderFlow method (type1) gives compile error.
Because of that, I throw my exceptions below:
throw new MessageHandlingException(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build(), new NoSuchMethodException("Failed"));        Is it correct way or is there a way for this process?